# SQL Search and Compare function

Tags: sql, count, case

I know very little about MS-SQL, but I need to perform a report.

I've this query:

```
Select
 a.HPD_CI as HPD_CI_Grouped,
count(a.HPD_CI) as HPDCant, b.submit_date
  From
  HPD_Help_Desk a, Tiempos_Grupos b--, Tiempos_grupos b
  GROUP BY a.HPD_CI, b.submit_date
```

And the result of this is:

```
HPD_CI_GROUPED  HPDCant SUBMIT_DATE  
ADSL1          1    2013-04-10 19:22:59.0
ENL001         4    2013-04-10 19:22:59.0
OSE001        18    2013-04-10 19:22:59.0
OSE002         9    2013-04-10 19:22:59.0
OSE003         1    2013-04-10 19:22:59.0
REF0001       44    2013-04-10 19:22:59.0
REF0002       11    2013-04-10 19:22:59.0
REF0003        8    2013-04-10 19:22:59.0
```

Actually what I'm doing is counting, but What I need is to compare the SUBMIT_DATE with the next one, and COUNT only IF the next submit_date exist between a defined range (days).

Let's say I define "6 days"... I found that OSE001 has 2013-04-10 19:22:59.0 as submit_date, If there is another OSE001 between 2013-04-10 19:22:59.0 and 2013-04-16 19:22:59.0, then it must count, else don't.

It could be something similar to:

```
COUNT(CASE Submit_Date - **NEXT**submit_date < 6 days then 1 else 0 end)
```

(of course that example doesn't work because I don't know how to call **NEXT**date)

Comment: Shouldn't you have some join condition in the `from` clause?

Comment: Because I don't know too much about SQL. I didn't know the JOIN funciont. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell from your question if you've got two tables already or not, but the idea is something like this:

```
SELECT a.HPD_CI as HPD_CI_Grouped
      ,a.submit_date
      ,COUNT(*) 
FROM HPD_Help_Desk a
JOIN Tiempos_Grupos b
  ON a.HPD_CI = b.HPD_CI
    AND b.submit_date BETWEEN a.submit_date AND DATEADD(DAY,6,a.submit_date)
GROUP BY a.HPD_CI, a.submit_date
```

Using BETWEEN in the join criteria allows you to pull back every row within 6 days for the same HPD_CI value.